# Finite sets of complex numbers with equal power sums are equal

Tags: complex-analysis

This problem is from the book Theory of Complex Functions (Remmert)

Let $a_1,..., a_n, b_1, ..., b_n \in \mathbb{C}$  and satisfy $\sum_{v=1}^n (a_v)^k  = \sum_{v=1}^n (b_v)^k , \forall k \in \mathbb{N} $

Show that there is a permutation $\pi$ of $\{1, ..., n\}$ such that $a_v = b_{\pi (v)}, \forall v \in \{1, ..., n\}$

Comment: Since it's complex analysis, probably [this argument](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1011946/83702) (with the appropriate modifications) is expected.

Comment: It's on chapter one exercise two on Remmert's book so I'm guessing there has to be another, more basic, solution that doesn't use concepts that are not yet explained at that point.

Comment: Hint: Consider the polynomials $P$ and $Q$ in $\mathbb C[X]$ defined by $$P=\prod_\nu(X-a_\nu)\qquad Q=\prod_\nu(X-b_\nu)$$

Comment: One could of course invoke algebra and note that the power sums generate the ring of symmetric polynomials, so equal power sums implies equal elementary symmetric polynomials, which gives the result too. But I'm not sure whether Remmert would assume that as known. And that is independent from complex analysis, so wouldn't really fit.

Comment: ...Hence equal sums for every $k$ from $1$ to $n$ suffice to conclude.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.**

Name $\sum_{v=1}^n (a_v)^k = p_k(a_1, \dots, a_n)$

Based on [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities), the  [elementary symmetric polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) $e_0(a_1, \dots, a_n), e_0(a_1, \dots, a_n), \dots ,e_n(a_1, \dots, a_n)$, are uniquely defined.

Hence, $(a_1, \dots, a_n)$ are the roots of a uniquely defined ploynomial with degree equal to $n$. $(b_1, \dots, b_n)$ are the roots of the same polynomial. Therefore the $n$-uple $(b_1, \dots, b_n)$ is just a permutation of the $n$-uple $(a_1, \dots, a_n)$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:
For $|a t | < 1$ we have 
$$\log \frac{1}{1-a t} = \sum_{k \ge 1} \frac{a^k t^k}{k}
$$

therefore, from the hypothesis we conclude that for $|t|$ small enough
$$\sum_{v=1}^n \log \frac{1}{1-a_v t} = \sum_{v=1}^n \log \frac{1}{1-b_v t}$$

and so

$$\prod_{v=1}^n ( 1 - a_v t) = \prod_{v=1}^n ( 1 - b_v t)$$